# reset for loop counter

Tags: zsh, for

Simple question: if I have a `for` loop (zsh) over an unreliable list, by which I mean the list contains entries that can't be predicted beforehand, then can I reset the `for` loop counter? This demonstrates what I'm asking for:

```
# e.g. list=(1 5 2 9)
for i in $list ; do
    [[ $i = 2 ]] && i=${list[1]}
done
```

(This example will obviously loop forever if it worked.)

I can only think of doing it like this:

```
for ((j=1; j<=${#list}; j++)); do
    [[ ${list[$j]} = 2 ]] && j=1
done
```

Is there a simpler way of doing it? ("Simpler" meaning easier to follow with the eye what you're doing.)

Comment: If the list was `(1 5 1 2 9)`, how would `zsh` know which `1` `i=${list[1]}` should bring you back to?

Comment: Other than the cosmetic replacement to `(( list[j] == 2 )) && j=1` or `(( list[j] == 2 && j = 1))`, I don't think you'll get any much better.

Comment: I only need to reset to the beginning of the list, which I should have mentioned. The reset position is not dependent on the contents of `list`.

Comment: No, I was fearing I would not get any better. I was hoping for some magical builtin command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
alias   forever='while ((1))' \
      try-again='continue 2'  \
        ok-done='break'

forever {
  for i ("$list[@]") {
    (( i == 2 )) && try-again
  }
  ok-done
}
```

Note that you need `"$list[@]"` instead of `$list` if you don't want to omit the empty elements.

Not a lot more legible than:

```
for ((i = 1; i <= $#list; i++)) {
  (( list[i] == 2 )) && i=1
}
```

though.

Comment: No, not really, but its an interesting way of doing it that didn't occur to me.